# Over length limit on PHP POST payload in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have a form with a whole lot of data in it. One of the values can have literally hundreds of options, presented as a big array (much like a huge set of checkboxes or radio buttons). The length of this data (encoded) is 45,500+ characters.

When the form gets `POST`ed to Laravel, the data is iterated over, and the various pieces of the form data are acted on. One of the things it's doing is looking for an `item` key in each of the array items.

Laravel is throwing an error that the array key `item` doesn't exist, and (due to my code) doesn't handle it gracefully at the moment.

I've taken the whole `POST` payload, used `parse_str` to parse it, and iterated it manually outside of Laravel, and there's no array item that does not have the expected `item` key. Other forms using the same code base don't fail, if they have smaller payloads.

My question is, even though I'm not exceeding the actual `POST` size limit, can I possibly be breaking the `max_input_vars` limit on the server, and failing to get an accurate PHP object from the `POST` payload? Is there another setting that may be truncating this payload?

Comment: Might want to take a look at `max_input_vars`, `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your main `php.ini` file. Have you check your apache logs in either `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (redhat) or `/var/log/apache2/error_log` (ubuntu)?

Comment: You could be, so increase the `max_input_vars` and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe paginate your form, store the results in a cookie, or store them to a (validated) database table. My inclination would be, if your form is that massive, your user experience is probably also terrible, and you can fix both the user experience and the form data with pagination and intermediate storage elements.